# Binding error with converter

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, converters

I have MdiContainer in my viewModel that I create dynamically:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
         MdiContainer = new TabbedMdiContainer();
    }                                          
    public TabbedMdiContainer MdiContainer { get; private set; }
```

In Xaml I set content of this container to mdihost:

```
<docking:TabbedMdiHost x:Uid="ALTabbedMdiHost" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="True" Content="{Binding MdiContainer}" IsCloseButtonOnTab="False"/>
```

When I create dynamically new tab with background image, I want that image to fill height and width of the mdiContainer. For this purpose I made made binding for image height and width.

```
 var height = new Binding("ActualHeight") { Source = MdiContainer, IsAsync = true};
 var width = new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = MdiContainer ,IsAsync = true};
 _img.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, height);
 _img.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, width);
```

The problem is that height includes MdiContainer height **with header height**, and I need height of the MdiContainer **without header height**.

So I created converter in different class:

```
public class ImageSizeConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double) value - 1000);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

but when Im trying to add converter to binding value :

```
 var height = new Binding("ActualHeight") { Source = MdiContainer, IsAsync = true, Converter = ImageSizeConvertor};
```

I get error *Class name is not valid at this point*. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found error) 
`var height = new Binding("ActualHeight") { Source = MdiContainer, IsAsync = true, Converter = new ImageSizeConvertor() };`